# How to Disable turbolinks on All links_to(througtout the app)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to Disable turbolinks througtout the app.
for example

**1.html file**

```
index.html.erb
<%=link_to 'add',"data-turbolinks" => "false"%>
```

**2.html file**

```
new.html.erb
<%=link_to 'add',"data-turbolinks" => "false"%>
```

so i have many html files how to do this all link_to after its possible?

Answer (score 0):

To remove turbolinks across whole app in Rails 5, in application.html.erb remove 
   `media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'`
from stylesheet_link_tag.

Also remove 
    `'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'`
from javascript_include_tag.

You should also remove the turbolinks gem and in application.js remove `//= require turbolinks`